# Invoking API from WSO2 store causing "101500 - Error in Sender"

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, wso2

I have configured our API inside WSO2 API manager, created one Application, generated keys and subscribe to one API from the application. Now while I am invoking the API from the WSO2 API store API Console, getting below error:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
  <am:code>101500</am:code>
  <am:type>Status report</am:type>
  <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
  <am:description>Error in Sender</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

By initial investigation and googling I thought of some certificate error for which the API manager couldn't get the response from the API deployed server, but no luck. And also the server where APIs are deployed is a http tomcat server. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks & Regards,
Surodip

Comment: do you see any error logs?

Comment: My WSO2 api manager is deployed in https and api depoyed in http, can I invoke the http api from https wso2 api console?

Comment: No you can't. The browser doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the log got KeyValidator Error, which was due to KeyValidatorClientType was "ThriftClient". Changing this to WSClient solved the issue. Thanks all for your support.